# How to write values within nested nodes in a OpenCV -based XML FileStorage?

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

I would like to write several values (Value_1, ..., Value_N) within nested nodes in an OpenCV::FileStorage -based XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<A>
    <B>
        <Value_1>1</Value_1>
        ...
        <Value_N>N</Value_N>
    </B>
</A>
```

What would be the C++ code to accomplish that?

```
FileStorage fs(file, FileStorage::APPEND);
fs << "A->B->Value_1" << 1; // ???
...
fs << "A->B->Value_N" << N; // ???
```

Comment: Which XML library are you using? If your answer is _"none"_ - change that. [OpenCV's Filestorage seems to support lookup. I recommend checking its docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d56/classcv_1_1FileStorage.html).

Comment: Yes, I am using FileStorage, but I cannot write values in nested nodes...